# Use user set custom cursor Java

Tags: java, swing, mouse-cursor

I know that it is possible for users to define their own system-wide cursors on Windows and OSX. However, I haven't found any way to use those cursors in a Java class.

For example, say I have a JFrame, and a custom drawn component, like so:

[image: Link in JFrame]

This cursor was set using `setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR))`. But I want to use the **link** cursor set by the user so the application is more integrated with the OS. Is there any way to *not* use the Java defined link cursor? Do I need to explicitly ask for a file? Or do I need to use JNA or something?

**---EDIT---**

I think I need to make the question more clear.

Say the user set their system-wide link cursor (the cursor that appears when hovering over a link, say in a web browser) to a picture of a banana. How do I switch to the banana cursor when hovering over a custom-drawn component?

Comment: Does it only occur on MacOS or have you tested it on Windows as well?

Comment: I've tested it on Windows. However, I know for a fact that the `getPredefinedCursor` method doesn't return a user set one; I just don't know why. There is a `cursor.properties` file in the JRE that defines 'system' cursors returned by the `getSystemCustomCursor`, but that method only works with cursors listed in that file.

Comment: I also don't want to modify the JRE (obviously).

Comment: Possibly you could just take the event when you hover over something (where you want the banana to appear) and just set the cursor as such from a loaded image (if you know how to do that)

Comment: I would do that, except I don't want to force the user to submit an image. It would be better if I could use the one set in [this dialog](http://cdn3.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/image100.png).

Comment: This is probably a native thing. One would assume that since a user-defined cursor is platform-dependent, it must be obtained in a platform-dependent way. Not all platforms allow a user-defined cursor. I'm pretty sure OSX doesn't.

Comment: OK thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried `jLabel1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));` this method should get the system cursor as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help; however, I have already tried something similar, `setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR))`. But I would like to use the user cursor if they have one set, as one can do on Windows.